# How do I download all the assets loaded by a webpage into a directory?

Tags: firefox

I want to download and study every javascript file and ajax loaded resource that a particular webpage calls. It would be great if I could some how get the browser or some other tool to save all the resources that the webpage makes the browser load into one directory. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use wget, not firefox.  [Here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget) is a quick guide that is handy.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not familiar with the command line, you can use Gwget (which is a GUI for the wget tool suggested by Brian). Selecting 'Download page requisites' in the preferences should give you what you need.